# What are the smallest neurons ever identified?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy, neurophysiology

What are the smallest neurons ever measured? I'm happy with any superlatives, such as the thinnest axons or dendrites, smallest somata etc. Thank you :)

Comment: I think, personally, that this question is too broad. Narrowing it down to a specific species would help for example.

Comment: Across all species that have a nervous system. It's just about absolute size.

Comment: The definition of neuron being an electrically excitable cell that works in concert with others of its kind to translate sensory input to motor output.

Comment: For whatever it's worth - Given the nature of the question it may be advisable to cross-post on Biology.SE. However, the broad scope may become an issue in terms of question closure.

Comment: Define the term "smallest" because, just as @AliceD said, the question is way too broad, neurons generally are not defined by size, and whatever measurement system you're trying to use to measure these neurons may not be applicable to these cells.